# Return Placeholder in Python

Tags: python

I'm returning several variables from a function in python:

```
mydb, mydb_name, instance_col = set_db()
```

However, of all those variables only `instance_col` is being used.

Is there a way of not specifying unused variables when returning them from python?

Comment: By convention, use `_` -- thus, `_, _, instance_col = set_db()`

Comment: `*_, instance_col = set_db()` - since you're only interested in the last elem

Comment: That's it. Great! Thanks!